# Get specific value from string read from stream

Tags: c#, string, stream

I have a string that was read from a stream using stream reader. This was after a WEB API call and get the response from the request. For a cleared view, here is my code.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("SOME URL");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);

string s = reader.ReadToEnd();

resStream.Flush();
resStream.Close();
reader.Close();
```

My string (s) there have a value of "value1=sometring1&value2=somestring2". I want to get somestring1 and sometring2. I think there's a better way to do this and not convert the whole stream as a string to get each value. Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you expect this to be at the same line?Then you could read line by line until you've found them.

Comment: I'm not really sure. This came from the facebook API.

Comment: Well actually you need to read data out of the stream in order to work with it so reading it into a string and afterwards splitting it seems like the right option for me. I'd suggest using `var parts = s.Split(new char[] { '&' });` which seperates by the & character. Afterwards you can split again by the = character.

Comment: I've thought about doing this but I also thought that there's a better way to do this without doing so much work.

Comment: If the stream has line breaks you can read each line and process it.  Otherwise you're stuck with one character at a time or the whole stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert the stream to a `string` then you can easily get somestring1 and sometring2 with `System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s)`

Comment: This is the simplest and most effective answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reading into the string and afterwards splitting the data using a method like the following one:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> SplitValuePairString(string originalString)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(originalString))
    {
        var keyValuePairs = originalString.Split(new char[] { '&' });

        foreach (string keyValuePair in keyValuePairs)
        {
            var parts = keyValuePair.Split(new char[] { '=' });

            if (parts.Length == 2)
            {
                result.Add(parts[0], parts[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can parse your string response with a `Regex` (if it always has this number of parameters, else you will have more results in the `MatchCollection`) :

```
MatchCollection results = Regex.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd(), "=([a-z]*[0-9]*)");

string value1 = results[0].Groups[1].Value;
string value2 = results[1].Groups[1].Value;
```

This code returns exactly from the string `"value1=sometring1&value2=somestring2"`:

```
somestring1
somestring2
```

Comment: @ljpv14 Just to know, for curiosity, why is my response deserves a -1 ? It works a results exactly what asked. So please feel free to answer me to know what is wrong in my code.

Comment: @tofutim I thought it was just question of code on StackOverflow. I just wrote code to help as I can but here I do not understand what is wrong and why I deserve a -1 with a fully working solution.

Comment: it is true that if you do reader.ReadToEnd() that you are pulling the entire string out